# Alter sales_flat_order table any risk?

Tags: database

I am developing an extension that will be probably used by 1000+ stores and needs to add 1 extra field into table sales_flat_order.

```
ALTER TABLE `".$obj->getTable('sales_flat_order')."` 
               ADD `new_field` TINYINT NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

sales_flat_order is very important table I am wondering if there ANY risk with this operation? If there is any even tiny risk for that, than I will rather create extra table with fields `order_id | new_field`.

Tnx!

Comment: Nope, this is not question how to add custom fields to sales_flat_order, it is question how safe is to use alter table for sales_flat_order.

Comment: @Raphael at Digital Pianism ,i did not thought it duplicate question,bcoz of user asking the question for  is there any risk of add a columns ta order table.Does not ask abound how a columns will add to sales

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there would be any issues, just make sure the upgrade script uses `addColumn` or `addAttribute` instead of a raw SQL query (as its considered bad practice).